# scheduling n people with given time of travel

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

this is a puzzle but i think it could be a classical algorithm which i am unaware of :

> There are n people at the bottom of a mountain, and everyone wants to go up, then down the mountain. Person i takes u[i] time to climb this mountain, and d[i] time to descend it.
>    However, at same given time **atmost** 1 person can climb , **and** .**atmost** 1 person can descend the mountain. Find the least time to travel up and back down the mountain.

---

**Update 1 :**
well i tried with few examples and found that it's not reducible to `sorting` , `or getting the fastest climbers first` or vice versa . I think to get `optimal` solution we may have to try out all possible solutions , so seems to be `NP complete`.

---

**My initial guess: (WRONG)**
The solution i thought is greedy : sort n people by start time in ascending order. Then up `jth person up` and `kth down` where `u[j]<= d[k]` and `d[k] is minimum from all k persons on top of mountain`. I am not able to prove correctness of this .

---

Any other idea how to approach ?
A hint would suffice.

Comment: If person A takes 5 minutes to ascend, and persons B and C take 2 and 3 minutes respectively to descend, can A ascend and B and C descend in 5 minutes (i.e. more than 1 person can descend, one at a time, while one person ascends), or isn't that allowed? If it is allowed, the problem seems fairly trivial of just letting them climb one by one, order not being particularly important (at least as far as I can see).

Comment: not allowed . constraint :`atmost 1 can ascend and atmost 1 can descend at given instant of time`

Comment: Although there can be 1 ascending **and** 1 descending at the same time am I right?

Comment: yes , this is possible.

Comment: It seems to me like a scheduling problem. Take a look at this google search result: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap17.htm

Comment: Very simple counter example: when all the u values are greater than d values, your algorithm will never run.

Comment: Can we assume that there is no limit on the number of people that can be at the top of the mountain at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to think in  the following manner: if the people are not sorted in ascending order of time it takes them to climb the mountain than what happens if you find a pair of adjacent people that are not in the correct order(i.e. first one climbs longer than second one) and swap them. Is it possible that the total time increases?

Comment: Yes, of course. Example: u=[100, 99], d=[100, 1]. So how does that help? I have no idea where you want to lead us.

Comment: In this example both climbing times are the same. OP will have to think of the correct order if several climbing tines are equal. Please note my answer is not a full solution but only a tip(as requested by OP)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is incorrect. Consider

```
u = [2,3]
d = [1,3]
```

Your algorithm gives ordering `0,1` whereas it should be `1,0`.

I would suggest another greedy approach:

- Create `ordering` list and add first person.
- For current ordering keep track of two values:

  - `mU` - time of last person on the mountain - time of the end
  - `mD` - time of earliest time of first descending
- From people who are not ordered choose the one which minimises `abs(mD - d)` and `abs(mU - u)`. Then if `abs(mD - d) < abs(mU - u)` he should go at the beginning of `ordering`. Otherwise he goes at the end.

Some tweak may still be needed here, but this approach should minimise losses from cases like the one given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will only work with n <= 24.

This solution will require **dynamic programming** and **bit-mask** technique knowledge to be understood.

***Observation***: we can easily observe that the optimal total climb up time is **fixed**, which is equalled to the          total climb up time of n people.

For the base case, if n = 1, the solution is obvious.

For n = 2, the solution is simple, just scan through all 4 possibilities and calculate the minimum down time.

For n = 3, we can see that this case will be equal to the case when one person climb up first, followed by two.
And the two person minimum down time can be easily pre-calculated. **More important**, this two person then can be **treated as one person** with up time is the total up time of the two, and down time is the minimum down time.
Storing all result for minimum down time for cases from n = 0 to n = 3 in array called 'dp', using bit-mask           technique, we represent the state for 3 person as index 3 = 111b, so the result for case n = 3 will be:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      dp[3] = min(dp[(1<<i)] +  dp[3^(1<<i)],dp[3]);
 }
```

For n = 4... 24, the solution will be similar to case n = 3.

**Note:** The actual formula is not just simple as the code for case n = 3(and it requires similar approach to solve as case n = 2), but will be very similar,

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks sensible, but it may be over-simplified, could you describe it more precisely here?
From your description, I can't make out whether you are sorting or something else; these are the heuristics that I figured you are using:

- Get the fastest climbers first, so the start using the Down path
  asap.
- Ensure there is always people at the top of the mountain, so
  when the Down path becomes available, a person starts descending
  immediately.The way you do that is to select first those people who
  climb fast and descend slowly.

What if the fastest climber is also the fastest descender? That would leave the Down path idle until the second climber gets to the top, how does your algorithm ensures that this the best order?. I'm not sure that the problem reduces to a Sorting problem, it looks more like a knapsack or scheduling type.